# Change speed at which Ajax Line Chart plots

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there a way to change the speed at which an AjaxToolKit Line Chart plots it's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at the moment. It is [hardcoded to 400 ms](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/Scripts/LineChart.js#L462):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    me.animateLines(me, lastStartX, lastStartY, 0, index);
}, 400);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback